# animate text from inputAccessoryView to tableView like iOS 11 messages app

Tags: ios, swift, animation, tableview, inputaccessoryview

I have a chat app and was very interested to implement an animation similar to that with the messages app.  Sending a message animates the text or media from the inputAccessoryView where the message is composed directly into the tableView/collectionView where it is displayed.

I presently am entering my message into a textView which is in an inputAccessoryView.  When the user presses enter, the message is added to the tableView dataSource and loaded into the tableView.

How can I present the animation appearance directly from the inputAccessoryView to the tableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this animation works like this:

1. When you type the text and press send, a new text bubble is added to the end of the messages table view by using tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation). This will add the bubble and animate the tableview upwards.
2. At the same time, a floating bubble view is created and placed over the text input view such as its width spans the leading edge of the text input view and the trailing edge of the new chat bubble that was inserted into the table view.
3. The floating bubble view is very quickly and simultaneously animated in two directions: its width changes until it arrives at the same width as the new bubble on the tableView and its y position changes at the same speed as the added chat bubble scrolls up on the tableView.
4. Then, when the animation finishes, the floating bubble is removed.

If you synchronize the floating bubble animation with the chat bubble really well it will seem as if the input text "became" the chat bubble.

I believe they used this create overlapping view -> animate -> remove overlapping view flow because if you pay close attention to the chat bubble during the animation, just at the end it looks like the booble changes just a little tiny bit, as if the floating bubble wasn't perfectly aligned.